# using css transform and scale to position image on hover

Tags: css, hover

I am applying this css transformation to an image in a table when the cursor hover over the image..

```
transform-origin: bottom right; 
-webkit-transform: scale(5) ;
```

I have tried every which way to get the origin outside the image, but it seems there is no way. If the origin is 'right' the image expands to the left obscuring the original image.

I would like to to put the transform image in a fixed location outside the table altogether! Or at least expose the small image.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question, also the question is not very clear. What's the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(25px, 25px, 100px);
  transform: translate3d(25px, 25px, 100px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" alt="">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of using `transform-origin: bottom right;` use `transform: translate3d(25px, 25px, 100px);` property. Hope it'll help

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Unfortunately it did not move the origin of the transformed image outside the original image. Why is a z-transform axis expected to move a 2d image?

Comment: Can you please update your html code, so people can understand better! And the solution i gave should work only you need to adjust your transform px